# line start string and end string matches then it needs to replace end string of a line and ignore any string that matches in between of same line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

Require a shell script for the below issue

elecj_test: |1009676|F|269.13348200|3|348415|237.06|0.00|0.00|||SSPPPSSSPSSS|UNTESTED||

If a line starts with **elecj_test:** and ends with **||** it needs to replace with **| |**

Here Space is added in between **| |**

In the middle of the line if it is found **||** it must not replace only it must replace at end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show your attempt and the issue you are finding.

```
echo 'elecj_test: |1009676|F|269.13348200|3|348415|237.06|0.00|0.00|||SSPPPSSSPSSS|UNTESTED||' | sed '/^elecj_test:/s@||$@| |@'
```

This changes the last occurrence only (end of line: `$`).

Comment: I did not check above one , but this worked for me  sed -n 's/^(elecj_test:.*|)|$/\1 |/p'